# Configuring InstallShield for customized uninstallation of installer

Tags: installshield

How do I configure my InstallShield setup project, so that when I uninstall my application, it should just uninstall the application and should not remove the fonts and .reg file that were also installed when I installed the application. I am using InstallShield Professional version to create my installer.

Answer (score 0):

Set *msidbComponentAttributesPermanent* (or simple permanent) attribute for components which related to font files and to .reg file.
You can do it directly in **Component** table or in InstallShieldIDE.